# bitrise could not find transporter at Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer

Tags: fastlane, bitrise

I am trying to upload ios archive to testflight using bitrise and fastlane but after archive success I get the error `"Could not find transporter at Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer"` and the workflow fails.

**Here is my fastlane file**

```html
platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
    lane :beta do
      increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "APPNAME.xcodeproj")
      match(type: "appstore")
      cocoapods
      build_app(workspace: "APPNAME.xcworkspace", scheme: "APPNAME")
      upload_to_testflight
      commit_version_bump(
        message: "Fastlane iOS: Released new build #{lane_context[SharedValues::BUILD_NUMBER]} [ci skip].",
        xcodeproj: "./APPNAME.xcodeproj",
        force: true
      )
      clean_build_artifacts
    end
end
```

Comment: `Xcode-beta.app` looks strange. Did you tell bitrise somehow to use an Xcode beta version instead of the normal one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 11 doesn't include the Transporter application anymore.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/301/

Comment: Where does one get the new Transporter app that session talks about?

Comment: Same problem here. Can you answer this, please?

Comment: @RobJust use xcode 10 when you build your project, you can select the xcode version from settings

Comment: Is there a solution for Xcode11 ? I am using bitrise and using fastlane command 'upload_to_testflight' upload to testflight and it is failing. "Could not find transporter at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/. Please make sure you set the correct path to your Xcode installation." any idea how to solve it?.

Answer (score 0):

I first got this error and so I downloaded [Transporter off the apple help page](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/en.lproj/static.html). However, Transporter 2x is not compatible with xcode 11. You need to use the version that is bundled with xcode 10x.

[This github thread](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15323#issuecomment-533939786) contains a download link to the appropriate binary.

If you have already installed the incorrect version of Transporter in the [default path that fastlane expects](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/7cab8341ec663eb58bb27af0bade422a8d561836/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/helper.rb#L202) `/usr/local/itms`, then use the environment variable `FASTLANE_ITUNES_TRANSPORTER_PATH` to specify a path to `iTMSTransporter.cmd`.

Specifying this path solved my issue and I was able to release to the apple store with xcode 11.